# hibernate mapping java type for oracle number(22,2)

Tags: java, hibernate, types, mapping

What should be the correct java type mapping to match oracle number(22,2) type in underlying table column, so that it doesn't overflow?

will it fit in `Double` or must use `BigDecimal` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both will do. But `double` can't be used to represent any decimal value, whereas `BigDecimal` can. Choose the one that fits best for your case. If it's used to represent monetary amounts, definitely use `BigDecimal`.